# Updating Firebase usertoken

Tags: android, firebase, token, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my application I try to update the usertoken with the following code:

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();    
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}
```

I declared the service in the Manifest:

```
<service android:name=".firebase.FirebaseIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

The problem is that the refreshed token is not updated (I am saving this token in users-database) while the app is not running. Do you know why this code is not running?
I need the token to send pushnotifications and if the user uses the app rarely the saved usertoken might be the old one when he should receive a notification.

Comment: Have you tried it on an emulator? Many custom Android ROMs (Huawei, OnePlus etc.) kill your app's background services when you close it and then, by default, don't let them restart.

Comment: I have not tried it on an emulator but it is the same problem on all used devices. But I can think of something else: I am sending the updated usertoken to my Firebase database when the token is refreshed. Is it possible that this is not working when the app is not running? So that the device can't send the new token back to Firebase?

Comment: Are you aware that the Firebase token is generated the first time the app is installed, and then refreshed only in rare cases (user deletes app data, instance ID deleted etc.)? Database access does work in a background service, whether the app is running or not (i.e. the user is still authenticated). Verify that onTokenRefresh() is being called when you first install the app; if this is not the case then perhaps you have declared your service wrong in the manifest.